# Parallel Queries in Postgres for Whitelisted Users

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing

My searches have revealed nothing, which tells me the answer might be no.  However, I'm hoping someone has a great idea.

In our database, parallel queries are mostly great, but they also tend to reward users who write terrible queries at the expense of everyone else.  I'd like to keep parallelism, but only for select roles/users.

Is there any way possible to do this, even if it means altering connection details at a query level?

Comment: Look at `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`  eg `ALTER USER <user> SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 1`

Comment: @Stu - This is fascinating...  this executed fine.  Can you tell me where in the docs you found this?  Also, max = 1 means a single parallel worker, and max = 0 means turn off parallel for that user?

Comment: Also, would you mind posting this as an answer?  I think this will help future lurkers who might have the same question know that there is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for whitelisting not blacklisting, I think your best bet is to `set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0` in the postgresql.conf file, then countermand that for specific users with `ALTER USER ... SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8` (or whatever value you want to set to).

I don't think you will find this in one place in the docs.  ALTER USER...SET... is one thing, the meaning of max_parallel_workers_per_gather is another thing, and you need to snap the Lego bricks together for yourself.

Note that your non-whitelisted users can still override their default values by, for example, manually running a SET command; so the assumption here is that they are just unaware, not malicious.

But this whole exercise seems questionable.  If you have enough people running bad queries they will happen in parallel anyway, just through the simple mechanism of new bad queries arriving before the previous one finished. At some point you need to deal with the people who run bad queries by educating them or replacing them or not letting them compose their own queries from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I think I am going to do that at the server level and make exceptions for individual users.  I fundamentally agree with your objection, but there is a double edged sword I won't bore you with.  We are non-IT.  We stood up our Pg database outside of IT, and it's become very popular with the user community, which has proven to be both good and bad.  Complicating matters are tools like Alteryx that users seem to love but brutalize our server.  If I could find a way to blacklist Alteryx and MS Access I would.

Comment: Following up, this has been fantastic.  I'm already noticing a huge improvement.  Thanks again.